# Наследование конструкторов в классе

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор

Начал изучать наследование, сделал базовый класс Man и новый класс Student. Проблема в том что я не понимаю как правильно составлять конструкторы и перегруженный оператор присваивания. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
class Man
{
    char * name;
    char * surname;
    int age;
    char phone[12];
public:
    Man()
    {
    name = nullptr;
    surname = nullptr;
    age = 0;
    memset(phone, 0, 12);
    }
    void InputData();
    char* getName(){ return name; }
    char * getSurname(){ return surname; }
    int getAge(){ return age; }
    char * getPhone(){ return phone; }
    void setName(const char * name);
    void setSurname(const char * surname);
    void setPhone(const char * phone);
    void setAge(int age){ this->age = age; }
};


class Student : public Man
{
    double average;
public:
    void InputData();
    double getAverage(){return average;}
    void setAverage(double average){ this->average = average; }
};
```

Ошибки :

```
Error   3   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   D:\AcademicGroup (3)\AcademicGroup (3)\AcademicGroup\Debug\AcademicGroup.exe    AcademicGroup
Error   1   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Man::Man(void)" (??0Man@@QAE@XZ) already defined in AcademyGroup.obj D:\AcademicGroup (3)\AcademicGroup (3)\AcademicGroup\AcademicGroup\Main.obj AcademicGroup
Error   2   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Man::Man(void)" (??0Man@@QAE@XZ) already defined in AcademyGroup.obj D:\AcademicGroup (3)\AcademicGroup (3)\AcademicGroup\AcademicGroup\Student.obj  AcademicGroup
```

Comment: Что значит "правильно наследовался"?

Comment: @soon, Значит что если я делаю вот такой конструктор то линковщик выдает ошибку. 
`Man::Man()
{
 name = nullptr;
 surname = nullptr;
 age = 0;
 memset(phone, 0, 12);
}`

Comment: Именно линковщик? Потому что ошибку должен выдать компилятор (если, конечно, вы не объявили `Man()` в классе). Добавьте тестовый случай и ошибку в текст вопроса.

Comment: @soon, добавил.

Comment: А какая структура проекта? У меня есть подозрение, что `Man::Man()` включается в несколько файлов, которые потом линкуются друг с другом.

Comment: @soon, в проекте 3 header файла для каждого из классов: Man, Student и AcademyGroup который использует класс Student. Если не создавать конструктор то программа работает отлично. И на всякий случай подключена #pragma once.

Comment: Реализация функций в `.cpp` файлах, или тоже в заголовочниках?

Comment: @soon, реализация Student и AcademyGroup в .cpp файлах, а Man в заголовочнике. А что из-за этого может быть проблема?

Comment: Скажем так, это корень проблемы. `Student` и `Main` собираются отдельно, поэтому в оба подключается файл `Man`. Вместе с объявлениями, туда подтягивается определение конструтора. Из-за этого и возникает конфликт ликнковщика

Comment: @soon, Действительно, вынос реализации конструктора в .cpp решил проблему! Спасибо!

Comment: @Костя Мазур: Приведенный выше код никак не может вызывать такой ошибки линкера, ибо конструктор `Man::Man()` объявлен `inline`.  Очевидно вы постите нам "ненастоящий" код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Резюмируя информацию из комментариев - проблема в том, что реализация помещается в заголовочный файл. Делать это крайне не рекомендуется по нескольким причинам:

1. Если данный заголовочный файл будет включен в несколько единиц трансляции, то при их линковке произойдет ошибка, так как одна и та же функция определена дважды (собственно, данная проблема и постигла ТС)
2. Мы лишаемся преимуществ раздельной компиляции. Когда объявления находятся в заголовочном файле, а реализация - в файле `.cpp`, то можно его один раз скомпилировать, а все последующие разы только линковать с остальными. (При условии, разумеется, что реализация этой части не будет меняться)

Comment: и еще один вопрос: у нового класса Student нету доступа к к полям класса Man, так как они в private. Как должен выглядеть конструктор по умолчанию в классе Student? Изменять поля сеттерами?

Comment: Можно сеттерами, но я бы посоветовал вызвать конструктор базового класса. [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules) расписано подробнее. Также я бы посоветовал Вам избавиться от всяких `char*` (и char[12]) в пользу `std::string`.

Comment: Но в приведенном автором коде реализация проблемного метода сделана `inline` и не может вызывать такой ошибки линкера, даже если она включается в несколько файлов. Я подозреваю, что автор скорее всего нас обманывает, показывая тут ненастоящий код, но тем не менее...